# When a hard check brings your credit score down, is the higher or lower (newer) score used in the current application?

Tags: credit-score

I'm applying for a business loan that will involve a hard check on my personal credit, but according to a credit tracker that I use, I'm very close to going from "Excellent" to "Very Good". The next hard check, if applied to one particular bureau, may lead to points lost that would push me beyond that limit.

Since the interest I'd get would only be practical for me based on my current score, and I wouldn't want the loan if they treat me as having a "Very Good" score instead, if my credit is pulled now, does the lender see my current score and act on that?

(i.e., any credit check after this one would see the new lower score, but this check would see the score before it got reduced)

Or does the act of them hard checking my credit and resulting reduction in the score mean that they see that resulting score, and my current "Excellent" score will essentially only be applicable for soft checks?

For argument's sake, let's presume this hard-check is the tipping point that will indeed lead to lost points that would push me over the boundary, which I know is a more complex issue itself. And let's also presume that the loan will definitely pull from the particular credit bureau that has the danger of going below the limit, and that raising my score is not possible (all credit paid down already etc.) in the timeline required.

This is for a US-based application. If lenders see both the "before" and "after" scores, then any indication of what some companies tend to go by, would be great! Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Comment: the score at the time they pull it, the hit comes after

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Thank you! Do you have a source or example to confirm that, or is it from experience? Appreciate it!

Comment: Also, as I think I understand it from previous answers here, the categories "Very good" and "Excellent" etc. (and to a degree the score itself) are more or less an invention of the agencies when informing _you_ of your score. Institutions that pull a credit report take _all_ the information in your credit history and will/may combine that in their own proprietary way to decide if, and at what rate, to lend money.

Comment: @BennyLewis unfortunately nothing I can provide publicly due to a NDA. But I am sure if you search for it, you will  have quite a bit of anecdotal references to it. In fact, the score drop is suspended in effect for similar type of credit being sought, such as a mortgage loan for 2 week, so anything coming through during that 2 weeks is considered "actively seeking credit" and will not give you additional hits, although they will show up in your inquiry section but their weighted impact is reduced.